# Find the particular element of a page using xpath and a set integer value which increments after each successful print

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to search a page for an element which prints a price (for that listing) and then increments the integer as to not print the same price again, but the price for the next listing. Here is the code I am using. It is already inside a for loop which I have not written out as it is extensive.

```
price_int = 1
price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='market_table_value'][price_int]")
print(price.text)
price_int+=1
#(Loop repeats)
```

When I replace price_int with a value such as 1 or 2 the correct respective price is returned. I am confused as to why the code is not working. It returns this error when built.

"selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/" is: [object HTMLDocument]. It should be an element."

Any help is appreciated, I get the feeling this is a simple fix but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: Although I solved the problem a different way, accepted solution is one possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='market_table_value'][" + str(price_int) + "]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass below way:

```
price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='market_table_value'][{0}]".format(price_int))
```

In the above line 0 represents the first argument to format the string. Don't change its value, it should be always zero since we are passing only one argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
"//span[@class='market_table_value'][price_int]"
```

Should be simply with Python's f string

```
f"//span[@class='market_table_value'][{price_int}]"
```